# What is the difference between -​- and - before a command option?

Tags: git

In git, we can modify commands with `--some-thing` or `-s`. From looking at the usage, it looks like the double-dash prefix is for option full-names while the single dash is for the abbreviation. Is that right or is there more to it?

Comment: Yes, it's a common agreement across all GNU-related tools (read: Linux :) ). While GIT itself isn't a GNU project, these rules are applied due to "operating environment"

Comment: Relevant Unix.SX question & answers:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21852/single-dashes-for-single-character-options-but-double-dashes-for-words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the fully named options (i.e., those prefixed with a `--`) have a shorthand prefixed with a single `-`. E.g., `git log --grep=mureinik -i` is equivalent to `git log --grep=mureinik --regexp-ignore-case`.

If the option takes an argument, note that the shorthand switches are separated from their arguments with a whitespace, while the longer names use the `=` operator. E.g., `git log -n 10` is equivalent to `git log --max-count=10`.

Comment: Re "*while the longer names use the = operator*", Spaces can also be used for long names. (e.g. `git log --max-count 10` works fine)

Answer (score 3):

That is indeed the difference.

Many commands allow you to "bundle" options. For those commands,

```
foo -bar
```

is the same as

```
foo -b -a -r
```

To distinguish bundled options from options with longer names, `--` is used to indicate that latter. That means that

```
foo --bar
```

only specifies one option.

This is a well known convention adopted by all tools that want to avoid confusion.